# Split up sum of products $\sum{a_i b_i}\approx(1/N)\sum{a_i}\sum{b_i}$ for uncorrelated summands?

Tags: summation

As the topic says, is $\sum{a_i b_i}\approx(1/N)\sum{a_i}\sum{b_i}$ possible when $a_i$ and $b_i$ uncorrelated? I have come across something like that very recently where this has been magically done without additional explanation and it makes intuitively sense. If I take a number example like 2*3 + 3*4 + 1*5 $\approx$ (6/3)*(12), but how can I justify this formally? Is there a name for this?

Thank you, M

Comment: ohh I think I found the solution.. it's when I multiply with (1/N) and take the plim and N->$\inf$, then I should end up with $E[a_i b_i]$. Now if both are uncorrelated, it is $E[a_i]\sum{b_i}$.

Comment: Doesn't that numerical equation say $23=24$?

Comment: ohh yea.. I meant approximation.. it should be equivalent in the limit, that is they are asymptotically the same.. I correct it into $\approx$

Comment: "it should be equivalent in the limit" --- what limit? I don't see any limit. Can you be more precise? In what sense is $23$ "asymptotically the same" as $24$?

Comment: Multiply the equation with 1/N. Take the probability limit of the expression on both sides.Essentially, imagine you had a large sum and $a_i$ and $b_i$ were uncorrelated. Then the above expressions converge asymptotically. The example above with N=3 is a rough approximation because the pair ($a_i$,$b_i$) are correlated. It is there to exemplify. If $a_i$ were all 2, we could take it out of the sum, as in this special case they uncorrelated, even for a very small N. For a large N, two variables cannot be entirely uncorrelated, therefore the above formula is a limit approximation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not with you. I don't know what a "probability limit" is --- how does it differ from an ordinary, everyday limit? What do you mean when you say two sequences of numbers are "uncorrelated"? What's the difference between converging, and converging asymptotically? If the $a_i$ are all $2$, and the $b_i$ are all $7$, you can take the $a_i$ out of the sum --- are the $a_i$ and $b_i$ uncorrelated in that case?

Comment: It's slightly more complicated. Correlation is not be defined in this case, as the X matrix would be singular. Probability limit is defined as $lim Pr(|x_n-x|>=\epsilon)=0$. Then $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$. If two variables are independent it implies they will be uncorrelated. So E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]. In the above example, if you take the probability limit after multiplying both sides by 1/N (so that the probability limit exists), you end up with E[XY]. If now X and Y are independent, you can take it out and revert back to a finite sample summation. So assymptotically both will converge.

Comment: Do the following. Open Excel and do a list of 50 random values in two columns A and B. Make a third column C with their product and sum it all up $\Sigma C$. Now make do also the sum of column one and two and use the formula  $\Sigma A/N \Sigma B$. Compare with $\Sigma C$. Calculate the error.. Do the same with a sample of 10000 elements. Calculate the error. You would see that the second one has a very low error <0.001%. The reason for this is because you created two random variables that should be relatively uncorrelated and both terms approximate asymptotically. This is what is meant by it

Comment: I've created an excel image for you. So you can see that when the correlation decreases the perecentage error between the two terms does to. I post it as quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Correlation and percentage error between the right hand side and left hand side of the formula. Note that the x axis refers to sample size + 10]

Here is a bare sketch of the solution. Please follow the commentaries to get an overview. In essence, $\sum{a_i b_i}\approx(1/N)\sum{a_i}\sum{b_i}$ are asymptotically equivalent for when $a_i$ and $b_i$ are uncorrelated. The reason for this is that if we multiply by 1/N both terms and take the probability limit, i.e.

$\sum{a_i b_i}/N\approx(1/N^2)\sum{a_i}\sum{b_i}$

$plim_{N->inf} \sum{a_i b_i}/N=plim_{N->inf}(1/N^2)\sum{a_i}\sum{b_i}$

by Markow Law of Large Numbers with unknown distribution it should be that

$E[a_i b_i]=E[a_i]E[b_i]$

which holds only for them being uncorrelated, i.e. Cov[a,b]=0.

The illustration provides an excel simulation of the above approximation formula. I checked the formula with a set of randomly created variables and how well the approximation works with increasing (sample size) and thus decreasing correlation.

Note that for a small sample starting with 10 (0 on the x axis) we have a relatively high correlation of 0.4 and percentage error (defined as percentage difference between the two formulas) of 0.16. Then with an increasing sample size, the error becomes insignificant, while the unsurprisingly the correlation decreases exactly in tow with it.

Comment: Hi, is there a proof for that approximation?