# Estimating $\sum_{k=1}^N a_kb_k$ given the means $\bar a_k,\bar b_k$ and determining the error

Tags: summation, approximation, average

I need to calculate the following expression:

$$\sum_{k=1}^N a_k b_k$$

I know the average values of $a_k$ , defined as $\overline {a_k} = {\sum_{k=1}^N a_k \over N } $ and $b_k$ , defined as $\overline {b_k} = {\sum_{k=1}^N b_k \over N } $.

I don't know the standard deviation but one extra information that I have is that with some accuracy, I can say that all the population $k=,..,N$ are in one of the three different states and I know that what fraction are in each states. In terms of numbers, it means that $a_k$ can only have 3 values. I don't know those values, but I know that for instance, 80% of N have the first value, $a_1$, 19% have the value of $a_2$ and 1% the value of $a_3$. The same kind of information is provided for $b_k$

If only knowing these quantities, I have to make some approximation, I would like to know how much error I am producing with that approximation. $N$ is relatively big.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Narj

Comment: Do you know anything else about the numbers, for e.g. are they all positive?

Comment: Yes, they are all real positive numbers (They are mol amount of some chemical agents in each cell with index k at time t and N is the total number of cells in a specific volume. I only can work with average values over all cells).

Comment: The error will almost definately depend on the standard deviation of your $(a_k)$ and $(b_k)$. More concrete: If $a_k \stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \mathcal N (a, \sigma_a)$ and analogosly $b_k \stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \mathcal N (b, \sigma_b)$ you'll want
$$\mathbb E (X - Nab)^2$$
where $X = \sum_{k=1}^N a_k b_k$

Comment: I'd point that the $\bar{a_k}$ and $\bar{b_k}$ of yours do not really depend on $k$, but on $N$ only. If you know only the average of $\{a_k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$ you can say quite nothing (except the Chebyshev inequality bound) about the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k b_k$, since the two sequences can oscillate pretty much. On the other hand, if you know the pointwise mean $\widetilde{a_k}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k a_j$ and the pointwise mean $\widetilde{b_k}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k b_j$, you know every $a_k$ and $b_k$, since $a_{k+1}=(k+1)\widetilde{a_{k+1}}-k\widetilde{a_k}$.

Comment: Thank you everyone. OK. What I understand so far is that I need more input. One extra information that I have is that with some accuracy, I can say that all the population $k=,..,N$ are in one of the three different states and I know that what fraction are in each states. In terms of numbers, it means that $a_k$ can only have 3 values. I don't know those values, but I know that for instance, 80% of N have the first value, $a_1$, 19% have the value of $a_2$ and 1% the value of $a_3$. The same kind of information is provided for ${b_k}$.  Is this of any help?

Comment: I also found this answer to a similar question: [link] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337643/split-up-sum-of-products-suma-i-b-i-approx1-n-suma-i-sumb-i-for-uncor)  I guess the difference here is that, they know the sequence of random numbers that they generated for plotting the graph, but I don't know all the values.

Comment: @Narj - the info on the three states and proportions is certainly pertinent and it would have been good to have that much earlier.  I suggest you should try http://stats.stackexchange.com and provide as much information you have on the data.

Comment: @Macavity - Thank you. Now I tried that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility, is a crude estimate of $\sum a_k b_k$ as $N \, \overline{a}\,\overline{b}$.

If we have $A_k, B_k$ as the sequences when $a_k, b_k$ are arranged in ascending order, we have the bounds (by Rearrangement inequality),
$$\sum A_k B_{n-k+1} \le \sum a_k b_k \le \sum A_k B_k$$

We also have the following bounds (by Chebyshev inequality), 
$$\sum A_k B_{n-k+1} \le \frac1N \left(\sum a_k \right) \left(\sum b_k \right) = N \, \overline{a}\,\overline{b} \le \sum A_k B_k$$

So both numbers are in the same (albeit possibly large) interval.  Unfortunately it is possible for both numbers to be at opposite extremes, unless you have some measure of how they could be spread and correlated. Not sure if you can do any better with the information at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, the largest the product can be (assuming all then numbers are positive and "reasonable size") is $N^2\overline{a_k}\overline{b_k}$ when all but one of the $a_k,b_k$ are zero.  The smallest it can be is zero if $a_k$ can be zero.  In an engineering sense, you probably have some information on how much variation is reasonable, which will allow much better assessment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can say much if you don't know anything about the distribution of the values within the sequences.

For example, you could have
$$
a=(1,0,1,0,\ldots),  \ b=(0,1,0,1,\ldots)
$$
and in this case the product is zero, while the averages are both $1/2$. But if you switch $b$ to be equal to $a$, now the product is $N/2$ and the averages are still both $1/2$.